# I am Using Geolocation API . Everytime I send a request i get a JSON Response with error 403?

Tags: android, google-api

**Using GeoLocation API**

Every Time I send a Post Request I get response as **Error Code: 403 Acess not Configured**.

I have followed all steps as mentioned in Google API Console.

I am using the following URL.

URL="https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=" and API_KEY="<"My_Key">"

Here is my Code

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL + API_KEY);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(mRequestString);
        post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        post.setEntity(se);
        response = client.execute(post);
        /* Checking response */
        if (response != null) {
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            mJSONResponse = convertStreamToString(in);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mJSONResponse;
```

JSON Response Which I always get is:

```
 {
    "error"{
      errors: [
       {
        "domain" : "usageLimits"
         "reason" : "accessNotConfigured"
        "message" : "Access Not Configured"
       }
      ],
      "code" :403
      "message" :"Access Not Configured"
     }
 }
```

Please anyone help me out to get over this problem....

Comment: did you read doc ... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/ search your error ...

Comment: Selvin-Yes I have followed the documentation given in api console for Geolocation API.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/) it can be possible with Below 2 Cases :

**Case 1 :** `dailyLimitExceededusageLimits`

> You have exceeded your daily limit.

**Case 2 :** `userRateLimitExceeded usageLimits`

> You've exceeded the requests per second per user limit that you
>   configured in the APIs console. This limit should be configured to
>   prevent a single or small group of users from exhausting your daily
>   quota, while still allowing reasonable access to all users.

Hope it Will Help.

Comment: Bhavesh :- I already increased the Set-per-user limits given in Quotas tab to 80-90 something .And uptill now total request made from single user is 58 . But Still Getting same error .